Convert Cstring and char C++ to string and char in C#, but not getting the result
I am trying to convert some existing function from C++ (MFC) to C#.
Not getting exactly the same result in C# what i am getting in C++.
This is the code in C++;
ss is CString
    CString ss = "ffffffe4"
    while (true)
    {
        csTemp = ss.Tokenize(" ", iCurPos);
        if (csTemp.IsEmpty())
            break;
        sscanf(csTemp, "%x", &iVal); // getting iVal as -28 here
        csCnvrt += char(iVal); // csCnvrt as ä
    }

what i tried in C# is
    string ss = szEncryptPwd;
            
    string csCnvrt = "", csTemp = "";
    Int32 iCurPos = 0, iVal = 0;

    string[] spstring = ss.Split(' ');

    foreach(string tmpstr in spstring)
    {               
         iVal = Int32.Parse(tmpstr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); // getting iVal as -28, which is same as c++ code result
         
         char vv = (char)(iVal);
         //char tmptest = Convert.ToChar(iVal);
         string vvst = Convert.ToString(vv);
         csCnvrt += vvst.ToString();  // getting "￤"(which is not same as c++)
    }

in both C++ and C#, iVal, i am getting equal. after that, not matching
any suggestions ?
Regards,
Gopi.

What are you getting in C#? In C++?

Please share a [mcve] for both languages.

The types char and char are very different. If you want a character denoted by the lowest 8 bits of the integer you’ll have to take those separately from the int. Char in .NET is a 16bit data type. ffe4 and e4 are definitely very different code points in UTF-16

C# string is always encoded in UTF-16, the size of char is 16-bit. However, your CSring uses ANSI encoding, and C# cannot directly process ANSI strings. To get the same result as C++, you need to first decode the hex string into a byte array, and then use the Encoding class of the system's active code page to transcode it into a C# string. If your app targets .NET Framework, you can use Encoding.Default, if it targets .NET core, you may also need to install the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package.
List<byte> bytes = new();
foreach(string tmpstr in spstring)
{               
    var iVal = int.Parse(tmpstr, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    bytes.Add((byte)iVal);
}

// .NET Framework
var csCnvrt = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes.ToArray());

// .NET core
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);
var csCnvrt = encoding.GetString(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(bytes));

